# como hacer consulta MySQL con Sequelize

Tags: javascript, mysql, sequelize.js, sequelize

Que tal soy nuevo con el ORM de Sequelize y trato de generar esta consulta

```
"SELECT CONCAT('F-',LPAD(SUBSTR(codigo,3,4)+1,4,'0'), '/',
            YEAR(NOW())) AS codigo
            FROM factura WHERE year(fecha_emision) = YEAR(NOW())
          UNION
            SELECT CONCAT('F-0001', '/', YEAR(NOW())) AS codigo
          ORDER BY codigo DESC LIMIT 1;"
```

alguna idea que me pueda auxiliar para como poder hacerla en los modelos de sequelize.

Answer (score 2):

Existen dos formas de realizar esto:

La forma mas simple, por defecto, la consulta devuelve dos argumentos (metadatos y resultado):

por un lado el resultado de la consulta y por otro un objeto con metadatos como (número de líneas afectadas/obtenidas, etc). Dado que se trata de una consulta sin especificar el formato, los metadatos son específicos del dialecto.

Algunos dialectos devuelven los metadatos "dentro" del objeto de resultados (como propiedades en una matriz). Sin embargo, siempre se devolverán dos argumentos, pero para MSSQL y MySQL serán dos referencias al mismo objeto.

Ejemplo de consulta sin especificar formato:

```
const [results, metadata] = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users`");
```

Ejemplo de consulta especificando formato:

En los casos en los que no sea necesario acceder a los metadatos, se puede especificar el tipo de consulta para indicarle a sequelize cómo formatear los resultados. `{ type: QueryTypes.SELECT }`

Ejemplo de un select simple:

```
const { QueryTypes } = require('sequelize');
const users = await sequelize.query("SELECT * FROM `users`", { type: QueryTypes.SELECT });
```

Otra forma es haciendo uso del modelo. Si se especifica un modelo, los datos devueltos serán instancias de ese modelo.

```
const projects = await sequelize.query('SELECT * FROM projects', {
  model: Projects,
  mapToModel: true // pass true here if you have any mapped fields
});
```

Lo que significa que cada elemento de `projects` es ahora una instancia del modelo Project

Saludos!